# CLWeeklyCalendarView is not working on iphone 4s,5,5s simuloter works fine on 6 & 6s

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use CLWeeklyCalendarView for showing calendar in application , but it strange CLWeeklyCalendarView is not shown any date & calendar , month in iphone 4s,5,5s simuloter but its work perfect in iphone 6, 6s simuloter , why this happen anyone knows , please help me , here i attache screen of iphone 4s[image: this is iphone 4s screenshot]

here is iphone 6 screen of CLWeeklyCalendarView[image: this is iphone 6 screenshot]

the code which i use for creating CLWeeklyCalendarView is:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
  [self.view addSubview:self.calendarView];
 }


//Initialize third party calendar
-(CLWeeklyCalendarView *)calendarView
{
 if(!_calendarView)
 {
  _calendarView = [[CLWeeklyCalendarView alloc]
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 
   CALENDER_VIEW_HEIGHT)];
  _calendarView.delegate = self;
 }

  return _calendarView;

 }

 #pragma mark - CLWeeklyCalendarViewDelegate

 -(NSDictionary *)CLCalendarBehaviorAttributes
{

return @{
         CLCalendarWeekStartDay : @2,                 //Start Day of the week, from 1-7 Mon-Sun -- default 1
         CLCalendarDayTitleTextColor : [UIColor yellowColor],
         CLCalendarSelectedDatePrintColor : [UIColor greenColor],
         };


}
```